# I want to display those value where price greater than 15.0 in laravel

Tags: laravel

This my .json file

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => An ice sculpture
            [price] => 12.5
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => cold
                    [1] => ice
                )

```
        [dimensions] => Array
            (
                [length] => 7
                [width] => 12
                [height] => 9.5
            )

        [warehouselocation] => Array
            (
                [latitude] => -78.75
                [longitude] => 20.4
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => A blue mouse
        [price] => 25.5
        [tags] => Array
            (
                [0] => cold
                [1] => ice
            )

        [dimensions] => Array
            (
                [length] => 3.1
                [width] => 1
                [height] => 1
            )

        [warehouselocation] => Array
            (
                [latitude] => 54.4
                [longitude] => -32.7
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => A blue mouse
        [price] => 25.5
        [dimensions] => Array
            (
                [length] => 3.1
                [width] => 1
                [height] => 1
            )

        [warehouselocation] => Array
            (
                [latitude] => 54.4
                [longitude] => -32.7
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => A Chainsmoker
        [price] => 99.5
        [tags] => Array
            (
                [0] => king
                [1] => wils
            )

        [dimensions] => Array
            (
                [length] => 7.1
                [width] => 25
                [height] => 7
            )

        [warehouselocation] => Array
            (
                [latitude] => 54.4
                [longitude] => -32.7
            )

    )
```

)
**Here I want to display the data only price greater than 15.0.
How Can I display using foreach in *Laravel***

`$ProductList=file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\resources\data\ProductList.json');
        $data=json_decode($ProductList,true);
        //print_r($data);

```
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'price' && $value > 15)
        echo $value;
    }
    print_r($value);
```

`

Comment: I access the file as 
$ProductList=file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\resources\data\ProductList.json');
     $data=json_decode($ProductList,true);     
     print_r($data);
This is I directly display the entire file in a array format but now I want to display only if price greater than 15.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in blade file

if name of your array is $data then you can use foreach like this

```
@foreach($data as $key => $value)
    @if ($value['price'] > 15.0)
        echo $value['price'];
    @endif
@endforeach
```

in above code i just print price but you can write your code at place of "echo $value['price'];"

i hope its helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter() function.

```
$result = array_filter($input, function($value) {
    return $value['price'] > 15;
});
```

In the example above, array_filter will loop through $input array and add values to $result array only if price is higher than 15.